# Filter table based on input value with Polymer

Tags: data-binding, filter, polymer, html-table

Is there anything in Polymer more or less equivalent to AngularJS 'filter' feature? I looked into template binding but couldn't find a way to filter my table based on the value of an input field...

```
<input value="{{ID}}">

<table [==> some Polymer magic here involving {{ID}}]>
   <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>VALUE</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>FOO</td>
       <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>BOO</td>
       <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>FAA</td>
       <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>BAA</td>
       <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Then typing "F" in the input field would have the table display only rows with values equal to 1 and 3, and going on with "O" would only leave "1" displayed ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this (today) is by generating your table from a filtered data model and reacting to key presses on the input using a Polymer `on-*` handler for keyup

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <input type="text" on-keyup="{{filter}}">
    <table>
      <tr><th>ID</th><th>VALUE</th></tr>
      <template repeat="{{d in filteredData}}">
        <tr><td>{{d[0]}}</td><td>{{d[1]}}</td></tr>
      </template>
    </table>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
      created: function() {
        this.data = [
          ['FOO', 1], ['BOO', 2], ['FAA', 3], ['BAA', 4]
        ]
        this.filteredData = this.data;
      },
      filter: function(e, detail, sender) {
        // Tests for anywhere in the string. Modify to match just the beginning.
        var regex = new RegExp(sender.value, 'i');
        this.filteredData = this.data.filter(function(d, idx, array) {
          return regex.test(d[0]);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/parive/2/edit?html,output

In the future, we're adding first class support for filter functions in expressions. See [1](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-expressions/commit/91b603597128a2a22741d8a027f39da9f68580c3) and [2](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-expressions/commit/ea5da4d8775b5044e7fb190ebacabd8b6dc3ca1f).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I get the idea, and am really eager to see the new feature you mention in action. However there must be a small glitch in the example on jsbin because typing "OO" leaves out "BOO" and only displays "FOO" ... Thanks indeed

Comment: Reply to my own comment: editing out the 'g' in RegExp second parameter in ebidel's code (as mentioned in the comment) gives the behaviour I expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Good code sample, but there were a bunch of errors (and perhaps some deprecated syntax?). Here's a corrected, working version: http://jsbin.com/parive/2/edit?html,output

I'll make some suggested edits to your entry as well.

Comment: Yep, syntax has changed. We used to not required {{}} on event handlers. However, you still want the <tr template> for browsers that do not support the template element. See https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#option-tr